# Trying to use two joins to find uncommon data in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have three tables. Table1 contains a list of all available products. The two other tables contain products sold at a store. I am trying to figure out how to find which products didn't sell at neither store.

I can find it for one store by doing:

> SELECT DISTINCT Table1.pname
>
> FROM Table1
>
> LEFT JOIN Store1
>
> ON Table1.pname = Store1.pname
>
> WHERE Store1.pname IS NULL

The problem comes when I try to add another join to figure out what hasn't sold. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your biggest problem is modeling. Do you really have a separate table for each store? If so, most of your problems such as this will go away if you can get the design right.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.pname

FROM Table1

LEFT JOIN Store1

ON Table1.pname = Store1.pname
WHERE Store1.pname IS NULL

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT Table1.pname

FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Store2  
ON Table1.pname = Store2.pname
WHERE Store2.pname IS NULL
```

Comment: I just realized that I made a mistake in my question. I should have said neither store instead of either store. Fixed it.

Comment: Okay, I tried this but it just returned everything in the Table1 instead of everything not on Store1 and Store2